# How to covert list to dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I get an error when I convert a list to a dictionary, because there are two words in one index's list like this :

**key_norm.txt**

```
['bimbel\tbimbingan belajar']
```

This what they say:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

This is my code, it's running if only one word is in each index's list.

```
#normalize word
DATA_KBBI = [kamus.strip('\n').strip('\r') for kamus in open('key_norm.txt')]

#convert to dict

dic={}
for i in DATA_KBBI: 
    (key,val)=i.split("\t")
    dic[str(key)]=val
```

I expect the output to be like this :

```
{'bimbel' : 'bimbingan belajar'}
```

Comment: This means one of the lines does not have `\t` in it.

Comment: yes, because it's actually one word

Answer (score 0):

As @Gerges says, your error is that one of the values in your `DATA_KBBI` does not contain `\t`. So `split` returns only one element and it can't be unpacked into `key` and `val`.

Depending on what you want to happen in the case you could try and instead use [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)

```
key, sep, val = i.partition('\t')
```

This will work, but if there isn't a `\t` character in your string `val` will be `''` (so will `sep`). It's up to you how you then deal with values like this. You could also test that the return value of split has a length > 1 before getting the key and the value but I think that partition is slightly more elegant.